# inject get head put on linux

Tags: linux, networking, proxy

I have looked everywhere and found millions of python proxy servers but none do precisely what i would like (i think :s)

I don't have had quite a bit of experience with python generally, but i'm quite new to the world of the deep dark secrets of the HTTP protocol.
What i think might be useful would be a very simple proxy example that can be connected to and will then itself try to connect to the address passed to it.

help me what i want is a proxy server that connects to http://mobileapps.blackberry.com, my internet service provider only allows  http://mobileapps.blackberry.com i want to use that URL to bypass through my VPS server to my PC at home

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you want a python proxy that acts as a VPN?

Comment: yes or anything that i can use to bypass my isp but through my server

Comment: Before I answer, what is your server running? That is, the name of the distro. E.g fedora Ubuntu red hat, centos, etc

Comment: my my server is running on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If your ISP only allows connections to that system, how would you connect to the proxy server in the first place? You're likely better off trying to do something like tunneling over DNS or ICMP. As a note, an ISP trying to put you in a walled garden may be detecting and mitigating these tunneling methods by disabling ICMP and only allowing outbound DNS connections to their own resolver.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using a VPN server instead. As you said your server is using Ubuntu 14.04, you should consider something such as OpenVPN. I have never used OpenVPN before, so I cannot help you with that. However, if you Google tutorials for OpenVPN, I see many that may be of help.

Comment: since you don't know about openvpn what about pptp vpn or other vpn

Comment: Those would work too, however  I do not use a VPN myself. I only know from what you are describing that VPN is a possible solution.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, there are tons of tutorials on Google. I searched up VPN server Ubuntu 14.04 and found a bunch of good tutorials.

Comment: i also found this one https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04 but the problem is how can i use that URL

Comment: @emenike on that link, you can follow the steps in that page.

Comment: They won't be able to get to the VPN server if they can only access that one domain.

Comment: OK but i am using that domain with simple server on my windows 7 PC  to bypass my isp so can't i use simple server on my server

Comment: what about TCP Headers

Comment: @emenike TCP headers have nothing to do with this. Are you trying to say you can only reach one page because your ISP blocked other sites? If so, that server can't get out of your ISP's block just by being another machine, if it's on that ISP's network.

Comment: yeah what i want is to use my server as man in the middle proxy.

Comment: i mean my home  PC to connect to my server then my server to use that domain as host to bypass my ISP to the internet

Comment: I see no problem, as long as your server is running on that one domain you  can connect to.